# Issues with 'require' when loading Rails models in a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I've embedded (or at least I *think* I've embedded) the rails models from my acme app into my Sinatra app using the following code, based off of a sample I had found on someone's blog. The rails app is in `/Users/chris/acme` and the Sinatra app is in `/Users/chris/acme/services/sinatra/sinatra.rb`.

```
RAILS_ROOT = '../..'
LIB_DIR = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib"
MODELS_DIR = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models"

require 'active_support/dependencies'
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += Dir["#{LIB_DIR}/**/"]
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += Dir["#{MODELS_DIR}/"]

require 'active_support/all'
require 'active_record'
::ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    YAML.load(File.read(
    File.expand_path('config/database.yml', RAILS_ROOT)))["development"])

require 'sinatra'

get '/user' do
  "#{User.first.id}"
end
```

When I visit `http://localhost:4567/user` I get the following error:

```
LoadError - no such file to load -- util/versioning:
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@acme/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/chris/acme/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Line 2 of `user.rb` is `require 'util/versioning'`, which is something that should have been autoloaded, but wasn't.

If I change line 2 of `user.rb` to `require '/Users/chris/acme/lib/util/versioning'` then everything starts working, but there's got to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `require 'util/versioning'` from `user.rb` and now it's working fine, including calls to `Util.Versioning` from within `user.rb`. This works with either a relative or an absolute `RAILS_ROOT`. I guess I seem to be misunderstanding how to use `require` properly as I'm not sure why I *don't* need to require a library that I'm definitely using in `user.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using an absolute path for `RAILS_ROOT`? Like

```
RAILS_ROOT = '/Users/chris/acme'
```

Comment: I get the same behavior as before even with an absolute path for `RAILS_ROOT`. (It seemed to work at first but then I realized that I still had a hardcoded absolute path for the `require` in `user.rb`.)